# Which chapter of the manga does Season 1 of Kimetsu no Yaiba anime end in?

Tags: demon-slayer

If you want to keep following the story of Kimetsu no Yaiba after that, you need to know which chapter of the manga the anime ends.

Which chapter of the manga does Season 1 of Kimetsu no Yaiba anime end in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [wiki](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_26), the 26th Episode adapts parts of **Chapters 51-54**.

The upcoming movie, *Kimetsu no Yaiba Movie: Mugen Ressha-hen*, [adapts the Infinity Train arc or Demon Train arc](https://myanimelist.net/anime/40456/Kimetsu_no_Yaiba_Movie__Mugen_Ressha-hen) from **Chapters 53-66**.